# sp_Blitz script output

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitz

I'm a very green DBA at my company, and ran the sp_Blitz script (on one of our test databases that is an exact copy of our production database), and I only get the message "Command(s) completed successfully.".

Is there a reason why I don't get a more detailed output?  Or is the output file written somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

As Denis Rubashkin said in a comment:

> If you had a look at the script text you would see that the script just creates a procedure `sp_Blitz`. You have to execute that proc (sample execution call with the most common parameters is in the bottom of the `sp_Blitz` script) to get an output you are waiting for.

You just created the procedure, but you still have to execute it. Here's some extra information if you have more questions:

There's a bunch of good resources you can check to get more information about any of the blitz procedures.

If you like to read:
This is the official documentation on the procedure, you can probably find everything you need here: [sp_blitz documentation](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/documentation/)

If you rather watch videos:
Brent has made some great YouTube videos where he goes through the usage of the of the Blitz procedures.

This one is for the SP_Blitz, but there are also some vids for SP_BlitzIndex / sp_Blitzfirst. (All very useful procedures)
[Brent Ozars youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QAL9itupMA)